# When I create a nested dictionary from a list, why is the length of my dictionary shorter than that of each list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

I created a script to process each item in a 3-column excel file exported as a .txt file into 3 lists (1 list for each column). There are 22 lines in the .txt file, including the header. With these 3 lists, I'm trying to create a nested dictionary where each column is a key, a key within a value, or a value within a value (ie: {Tag1:{Tag2:Tag3}...} for however many items there are in the lists.

When I zip these lists into a nested dictionary, it truncates the list and zips only 19 items into the dictionary, not 22. Could someone troubleshoot my code and see what the dictionary is doing to my list?

Here's the .txt file for reference:[image]

Here's my script:

```
import glob
source_file = glob.glob('file_path/test.txt')[0]
time = []
code = []
identifier = []
data_set = {}


for line in open (source_file,'r'):
  line_split = line.split('\t')
  tag_3 = line_split[-1].replace('\n','')
  tag_2 = line_split[1]
  tag_1 = line_split[0]

  time.append(tag_3)
  code.append(tag_2)
  identifier.append(tag_1)

data_set = {a:{b:c} for a,b,c in zip(identifier, code, time)}
```

EDIT: here's a link to a downloadable version to the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2s43FKt5BZgQldULXVOR0RBeTg/view?usp=sharing

EDIT 2: This should be the desired output:

```
data_set = {
'Tag1':{'Tag2':'Tag3'},
'0.1M':{'20':'10'},
'0.1MCD':{'2':'1'},
'0.25M':{'17':'1'},
'0.25MC':{'18':'1'},
'0.5MCN':{'16':'1'},
'0.MCD8':{'15':'1'},
'10':{'36':'5'},
'1029':{'75':'17'},
'1029A':{'22':'15'},
'1029B':{'49':'18'},
'1029BCD':{'23':'15'},
'1029BCDA':{'27':'18'},
'109B8N':{'63':'10'},
'1193D4M':{'51':'16'},
'1193D4N':{'2':'11'},
'1193D8M':{'17':'16'},
'11938N':{'25':'12'},
'1193CD4M':{'53':'16'},
'1193CD4N':{'83':'13'},
'118M':{'20':'16'},
'1193BCN':{'16':'7'},
```

}

EDIT 3: It turns out the dictionary truncates the value if there are duplicate values in the lists. Is there anyway to avoid this?

Comment: can you post the file in text so that people can debug?

Comment: Why dont you create dict when reading file? Also dont redefine built-in `dict` name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
s = [b for b in [i.strip('\n').split()  for i in open('file.txt')] if b]
final_data = {a:{b:c} for a, b, c in s}
```

Output:

```
{'1029BCDA': {'27': '18'}, '1029BCD': {'23': '15'}, '0.25M': {'17': '1'}, '118M': {'20': '16'}, '0.1M': {'20': '10'}, '11934D4N': {'83': '13'}, '0.5MCD8': {'15': '1'}, '1193D8M': {'17': '16'}, '1193CD4M': {'53': '16'}, '109B8N': {'63': '10'}, '10': {'36': '5'}, '1193D4M': {'51': '16'}, '1193D4N': {'2': '11'}, '0.1MCD': {'2': '1'}, '1193BCN': {'16': '7'}, '0.25MC': {'18': '1'}, '11938N': {'25': '12'}, '0.5MCN': {'16': '1'}, 'Tag1': {'Tag2': 'Tag3'}, '1029': {'75': '17'}, '1029A': {'22': '15'}, '1029B': {'49': '18'}}
```

Edit: using a `collections.defaultdict` for correct handling of duplicate values:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for a, b, c in s:
   d[a].append({b:c})
```

Comment: I'm receiving an error code that says "too many values to unpack" when I plug in your code

Comment: @superasiantomtom95 please post your desired output from the file.

Comment: @superasiantomtom95 Also, I made several changes, let me know how it works now.

Comment: It still says that there are too many values to unpack (referring to the 2nd line of code you provided). Not sure what's wrong on my end

Comment: Actually, if I run my normal script on the file, it works fine. However, the moment I have duplicate values in the tag1 column, that's when the problem arises. Python seems to override the duplicate values. Is there anyway to prevent this?

Comment: @superasiantomtom95 you can use a `collections.defaultdict`. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: suppose there are 2 duplicate values for the "0.1M" Tag1 value with 2 different Tag2 & Tag3 files (ie: the data set has 0.1M-20-10 & 0.1M-30-20 where the 1st value is Tag1, 2nd is Tag2, and 3rd is Tag3.

In this dictionary, the value would be stored as {'0.1M':[{'20','10'},{'30','20'}]}. How would I go about accessing the Tag2 or Tag3 value of the 2nd 0.1M value (30-20) or even the 1st value (How would I access the '30' and the '20' value)?

Comment: @superasiantomtom95 that data will be added to a list under the first tag.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary can't have duplicate keys. What you can do is to define dictionary to hold a list of values. In your case change {Tag1:{Tag2:Tag3}} to be {Tag1:[{Tag2:Tag3}]}

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called a “bag”. Try the [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects) class.